# Highcharts - Dynamic chart creation and unique data series

Tags: angularjs, charts, highcharts, typescript

I need to be able to draw multiple charts with variable data on the same page with one "create" button. My logic is as follows: upon clicking the create button my rest api sends data back for that particular chart. When I have the data I bind it to the series variable on my controller. Right now I have a "global" series variable on my controller and I update it each time data comes back from REST so all of my charts have the same values and look the same (did it as a proof of concept to see if drawing charts will work at all). How do I make it so each chart has it's own data series ? Do I need to set chart ID every time I create the chart and then find that ID and create series for it ? Here is my code

```
    <md-button class="md-raised md-primary"
         ng-click="chartGridCtrl.addChart()">Create
    </md-button>
    <div layout="column" flex>
        <md-divider/>
        <div flex ng-cloak>
            <md-grid-list
                    md-cols="1" md-cols-sm="2" md-cols-md="3" md-cols-gt-md="6"
                    md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="4:3"
                    md-gutter="8px" md-gutter-gt-sm="4px">
                <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="tile in chartGridCtrl.tiles"
                              md-rowspan="{{tile.span.row}}"
                              md-colspan="{{tile.span.col}}"
                              style="background-color: #00ad9c">
                    <md-card>Chart card
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div>
                                <snapshot-bar-chart // this is my custom directive for chart
                                        data="[chartGridCtrl.series]">
                                </snapshot-bar-chart>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </md-card>
                </md-grid-tile>
            </md-grid-list>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller (I omitted constructor etc):

```
export class ChartGridController {

    private series = [];
    private tiles:Object[];

    public addChart = () => {

       this.tiles.push(
       {
            title: "anotherTile",
            span: {row: 2, col: 2}
       });

    // get REST data and update series variable 
   };

}
```

Comment: I think that you can should be able to use id of your container for getting the chart and adding new series to chart in the right container.